# Pandas create column with names of columns with lowest match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Pandas dataframe where I have points and corresponding lengths to another points. I am able to get minimal value of the calculated columns, however, I need the column names itself. I am unable to figure out how can I get the column names corresponding to values in a new column. My dataframe looks like this:

`df.head()`:

```
        0      1           2  ...           6           7         min
9    58.0   94.0  984.003636  ...  696.667367  218.039561  218.039561
71  100.0  381.0  925.324708  ...  647.707783  169.856557  169.856557
61  225.0   69.0  751.353014  ...  515.152768  122.377490  122.377490
```

0 and 1 are datapoints, the rest are distances to datapoints #1 to 7, in some cases the number of points can differ, does not really matter for the question. The code I use to count min is following:

```
new = users.iloc[:,2:].min(axis=1)
users["min"] = new
#could also do the following way
#users.assign(Min=lambda users: users.iloc[:,2:].min(1))
```

This is quite simple and there is no much about finding the minimum of multiple columns. However, I need to get the col name instead of the value. So my desired output would look like this (in the example all are 7, which is not rule):

```
        0      1           2  ...           6           7 min
9    58.0   94.0  984.003636  ...  696.667367  218.039561  7
71  100.0  381.0  925.324708  ...  647.707783  169.856557  7
61  225.0   69.0  751.353014  ...  515.152768  122.377490  7
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: `DataFrame.idxmin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`df.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html):

```
In [549]: df['min'] = df.iloc[:,2:].idxmin(axis=1)

In [550]: df
Out[550]: 
        0      1           2           6           7 min
9    58.0   94.0  984.003636  696.667367  218.039561   7
71  100.0  381.0  925.324708  647.707783  169.856557   7
61  225.0   69.0  751.353014  515.152768  122.377490   7
```